# JSP's not supported in IceFaces 2.0.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

Last week IceFaces has released its new version 2.0.0. It was long been in the beta version and finally came out to final version. In the [release notes](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/ICEfaces+2.0.0+Release+Notes#ICEfaces2.0.0ReleaseNotes-newfeatures) it is specified as "**JSPs are not supported by ICEfaces 2.0 - use Facelets**". What does that mean?. Are we not suppose to write any JSP's?. What about the existing projects running on JSP files.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that IceFaces specifically doesn't support JSPs. It's the fact that IceFaces 2.0.0 is based on JSF 2.0 and it takes advantage of a couple of JSF 2.0 specific features.

A lot of the new JSF 2.0 specific features are simply not supported in JSP. So if any technology depends on those features, it automatically doesn't support JSP. *(this is one reason why it's so important for legacy JSF projects to migrate from JSP to Facelets ASAP).*

I put some references to authoritative sources on the wikepedia article about Facelets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facelets). This is the one from the official specification (emphasis mine).

JSF 2.0 (JSR 314, http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) specification, maintenance release 2, section 10.1:

> Facelets is a replacement for JSP that was designed from the outset with JSF in mind. **New features introduced in version 2 and later are only exposed to page authors using Facelets.** JSP is retained for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

From JSF 2.0, Facelets is the official view technology. Even if JSP is supported it will be minimal. Read more [here](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#facelets)

Comment: I know this fact. My question is why IceFaces says it doesn't support JSP. I have doubt on that. May be they have not clearly documented that.

Comment: they are stating the obvious. you can ask for clarification on their forum.

Comment: Thank you. Below reply is more detail for me.